# Classify the image by a field in its attribute table using QGIS software

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify, image-classification, raster-attribute-table

I created the attribute table of raster data in ArcMap software. There is a field that I added in the attribute table that I created. I can reclassify the image using the field I added to the image's attribute table in ArcMap software (I do it from Layer Properties ---> Symbology --> classified --> Fields --> Value). I opened this image in QGIS software, the attribute table I created was also opened. How can I classify the image in QGIS software according to the additional field I created in the image's attribute table?

Comment: symbology is not normally stored in a raster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the plugin raster attribute table. It does what you need I think: https://github.com/noaa-ocs-hydrography/qgis-raster-attribute-table-plugin

Comment: thank you for replying.